# tf.data.Dataset: The `batch_size` argument must not be specified for the given input type

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu, talos

I'm using **Talos** and Google colab **TPU** to run hyperparameter tuning of a **Keras** model. Note that I'm using Tensorflow 1.15.0 and Keras 2.2.4-tf.

```py
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import talos as ta
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def iris_model(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, params):

    # Specify a distributed strategy to use TPU
    resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
    tf.contrib.distribute.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
    strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)

    # Use the strategy to create and compile a Keras model
    with strategy.scope():
      model = Sequential()
      model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(4,), activation=tf.nn.relu, name="relu"))
      model.add(Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name="softmax"))
      model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.1), loss=params['losses'])

    # Convert data type to use TPU
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_val = x_val.astype('float32')

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
    dataset = dataset.cache()
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).repeat()
    dataset = dataset.batch(params['batch_size'], drop_remainder=True)

    # Fit the Keras model on the dataset
    out = model.fit(dataset, batch_size=params['batch_size'], epochs=params['epochs'], validation_data=[x_val, y_val], verbose=0, steps_per_epoch=2)

    return out, model

# Load dataset
X, y = ta.templates.datasets.iris()

# Train and test set
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, shuffle=False)

# Create a hyperparameter distributions 
p = {'losses': ['logcosh'], 'batch_size': [128, 256, 384, 512, 1024], 'epochs': [10, 20]}

# Use Talos to scan the best hyperparameters of the Keras model
scan_object = ta.Scan(x_train, y_train, params=p, model=iris_model, experiment_name='test', x_val=x_val, y_val=y_val, fraction_limit=0.1)
```

After converting the train set to a Dataset using `tf.data.Dataset`, I get the following error when fitting the model with `out = model.fit`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c812209b95d0> in <module>()
      8 
      9 # Use Talos to scan the best hyperparameters of the Keras model
---> 10 scan_object = ta.Scan(x_train, y_train, params=p, model=iris_model, experiment_name='test', x_val=x_val, y_val=y_val, fraction_limit=0.1)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _validate_or_infer_batch_size(self, batch_size, steps, x)
   1813             'The `batch_size` argument must not be specified for the given '
   1814             'input type. Received input: {}, batch_size: {}'.format(
-> 1815                 x, batch_size))
   1816       return
   1817 

ValueError: The `batch_size` argument must not be specified for the given input type. Received input: <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((512, 4), (512, 3)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>, batch_size: 512
```

Then, if I follow those instructions and don't set the batch-size argument to `model.fit`. I get another error in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c812209b95d0> in <module>()
      8 
      9 # Use Talos to scan the best hyperparameters of the Keras model
---> 10 scan_object = ta.Scan(x_train, y_train, params=p, model=iris_model, experiment_name='test', x_val=x_val, y_val=y_val, fraction_limit=0.1)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _distribution_standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, validation_split, shuffle, epochs, allow_partial_batch)
   2307             strategy) and not drop_remainder:
   2308           dataset_size = first_x_value.shape[0]
-> 2309           if dataset_size % batch_size == 0:
   2310             drop_remainder = True
   2311 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: It would be helpful for that last error if you could post a whole stack trace, because that function seems to be called at a bunch of places in this file, so I can't tell where you are: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.15/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py

Comment: I just edited the question, you can check the stack trace, thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that the problem with your code is that the training
and validation data is not in the same format. You are batching the
training data but not the validation examples.

You can ensure that they are in the same format by replacing the
bottom half of your `iris_model` function with this:

```
def fix_data(x, y):
    x = x.astype('float32')
    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
    ds = ds.cache()
    ds = ds.shuffle(1000, reshuffle_each_iteration = True)
    ds = ds.repeat()
    ds = ds.batch(params['batch_size'], drop_remainder = True)
    return ds
train = fix_data(x_train, y_train)
val = fix_data(x_val, y_val)

# Fit the Keras model on the dataset
out = model.fit(x = train, epochs = params['epochs'],
                steps_per_epoch = 2,
                validation_data = val,
                validation_steps = 2)
```

At least this works for me and your code runs without error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes, I think that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

from [github code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py) :

> ValueError will be
>           raised if `x` is a generator or `Sequence` instance and `batch_size` is
>           specified as we expect users to provide batched datasets.

Try using `batch_size = None`

Comment: I get another error in _distribution_standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, validation_split, shuffle, epochs, allow_partial_batch)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int

Comment: you should also set steps_per_epoch = None

Comment: It doesn't work, I get another error: ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor. I think you can easily reproduce the error by copying the short program

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following will fit your bill but something to try. All I have done is taken off the repeat() from dataset and batch_size=params['batch_size'] from model.fit

If the above is not what you are ready to sacrifice then please ignore the post.

```py
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import talos as ta
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

def iris_model(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, params):

    # Specify a distributed strategy to use TPU
    resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
    tf.config.experimental_connect_to_host(resolver.master())
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
    strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)

    with strategy.scope():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=4, activation=params['activation']))
        model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
        model.compile(optimizer=params['optimizer'], loss=params['losses'])

    # Convert the train set to a Dataset to use TPU
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
    dataset = dataset.cache().shuffle(1000, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).batch(params['batch_size'], drop_remainder=True)

    out = model.fit(dataset, epochs=params['epochs'], validation_data=[x_val, y_val], verbose=0)

    return out, model

x, y = ta.templates.datasets.iris()

p = {'activation': ['relu', 'elu'],
       'optimizer': ['Nadam', 'Adam'],
       'losses': ['logcosh'],
       'batch_size': (20, 50, 5),
       'epochs': [10, 20]}

scan_object = ta.Scan(x, y, model=iris_model, params=p, fraction_limit=0.1, experiment_name='first_test')
```

Comment: It's not working: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

That second error you get, in 
`_distribution_standardize_user_data`, when you don't pass the `batch_size` to fit.

The code you're running for that function is here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.15/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L2192

You didn't post a trace-back, but I bet it's failing on [line 2294](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.15/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L2294), since that's the only place where `batch_size` is multiplied by something.

```
if shuffle:
          # We want a buffer size that is larger than the batch size provided by
          # the user and provides sufficient randomness. Note that larger
          # numbers introduce more memory usage based on the size of each
          # sample.
          ds = ds.shuffle(max(1024, batch_size * 8))
```

It looks like you can shut it off by setting `shuffle=False`.

```
fit(ds, shuffle=False,...)
```

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error with shuffle=False. It's failing on line 2309, not 2294.

Comment: @SamiBelkacem, that'

Answer (score 0):

Could you remove, these lines from your code and try:

```
    dataset = dataset.cache()
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).repeat()
    dataset = dataset.batch(params['batch_size'], drop_remainder=True)
WITH THESE:
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.batch(128, drop_remainder=True)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
```

Otherwise what you wrote in `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` has something to do with the error.

Comment: Still not working. As you said, tf.data.Dataset has something to do with the error. But, the documentation says it is necessary to include it when using a Cloud TPU https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu#input_datasets