# Should we apply repeat, batch shuffle to tf.data.Dataset when passing it to fit function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras, tensorflow2.x

I still don't after having read documentation about `tf.keras.Model.fit` and `tf.data.Dataset`, when passing `tf.data.Dataset` to fit function, should I call `repeat` and `batch` on the dataset object or should I provide the `batch_size` and `epochs` arguments to fit instead? or both? Should I apply the same treatment to the validation set?

And while I'm here, can I `shuffle` the dataset before the `fit`? (seems like it's an obvious yes)
If so, before, after calling `Dataset.batch` and `Dataset.repeat` (if calling them)?

**Edit:** When using `batch_size` argument, and without having called `Dataset.batch(batch_size)` previously, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The `batch_size` argument must not be specified for the given input type.
Received input: <MapDataset shapes: ((<unknown>, <unknown>, <unknown>, <unknown>), (<unknown>, <unknown>, <unknown>)), 
types: ((tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32), (tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32))>, 
batch_size: 1
```

Thanks

Comment: fit shuffles data by default

Comment: Thanks Chris! What about the previous questions?

Comment: provide batch size and epochs in the fit function

Comment: So in the end I should just give the freshly loaded dataset calling anything (except data transformation) on it before passing it to the `fit` function?

Comment: Yeah, it's designed to shuffle during batching

Comment: Could you read the whole question post please?
I was mainly wondering about the `batch_size` and `epochs` parameters. I edited my question as I currently have a problem with `batch_size`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958437/tf-data-dataset-the-batch-size-argument-must-not-be-specified-for-the-given-i

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Can I get a clear answer to the firs question? And what about the validation set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's different ways to do what you want here, but the one I always use is:

```
batch_size = 32
ds = tf.Dataset()
ds = ds.shuffle(len_ds)
train_ds = ds.take(0.8*len_ds)
train_ds = train_ds.repeat().batch(batch_size)
validation_ds = ds.skip(0.8*len_ds)
validation_ds = train_ds.repeat().batch(batch_size)
model.fit(train_ds,
          steps_per_epoch = len_train_ds // batch_size,
          validation_data = validation_ds,
          validation_steps = len_validation_ds // batch_size,
          epochs = 5)
```

This way you have access to all the variables after model fitting as well, for example if you want to visualize the validation set, you can. This is not really possible with `validation_split`. If you remove `.batch(batch_size)`, you should remove the `// batch_size`s, but I would leave them, as it clearer what is happening now.

You always have to provide epochs.

Calculating the length of your train/validation sets requires you to loop over them:

```
len_train_ds = 0
for i in train_ds:
  len_train_ds += 1
```

if in `tf.Dataset` form.